# How can I display a Persona component in a CommandBar in React Fabric-UI?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to display a Persona component on the far right of my CommandBar component, which I use as a header for my application.

Here's a code snippet

```
const getFarItems = () => {
  return [
    {
      key: 'profile',
      text: <Persona text="Kat Larrson" />,
      onClick: () => console.log('Sort')
    }
  ]
}


const FabricHeader: React.SFC<props> = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CommandBar
        items={getItems()}
        farItems={getFarItems()}
        ariaLabel={'Use left and right arrow keys to navigate between commands'}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This throws a type error because the `text` prop expects a string and not a component. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the `ICommandBarItemProps` there is a property called `commandBarButtonAs` that the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/commandbar) state:

> Method to override the render of the individual command bar button.
>   Note, is not used when rendered in overflow

And its default component is `CommandBarButton` which is basically a [Button](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/button)

Basically there are two ways to do this.

1. Keep using Button, and apply your own renderer. Basically the `IButtonProps` you can add `onRenderChildren` which would allow you to add any Component such as Persona to render. This example would show you how it is done https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/qMoYQo

```
const farItems = [{
    // Set to null if you have submenus that want to hide the down arrow.
    onRenderMenuIcon: () => null, 
    // Any renderer
    onRenderChildren: () => ,
    key: 'persona',
    name: 'Persona',
    iconOnly: true,
}]
```

2. Or add your own crazy component not dependent on `CommandBarButton` but that means you need to handle everything like focus, accessibility yourself. This example would show you how it is done https://codepen.io/mohamedhmansour/pen/GPNKwM

```
const farItems = [
  {
    key: 'persona',
    name: 'Persona',
    commandBarButtonAs: PersonaCommandBarComponent
  }
];

function PersonaCommandBarComponent() {
  return (
    
  );
}
```

Comment: outstanding answer!
So easy to plug other Fabric buttons with this method.
The official docs could really do with such a simple and concise example.
 
I've just spent a few good hours butchering the official customisation examples to eventually end up on this answer. all is well now :) thanks so much